# PS3 HDMI issue "Resolution not supported"

Tags: ps3, technical-issues

I have my PS3 which connected it to my Samsung TV via HDMI cable that came with it. Everything worked fine for a couple of months until recently I started getting a message on the TV saying "Mode not Supported".

At first I didn't understand what was the cause of this issue but then I just turned the PS3 off along with the TV and after a minute of 2, I turned it back on and everything worked fine. That message came on its own, sometimes when turning on the PS3, and sometimes randomly during game-play the screen would flash and give the dreaded "Mode Not supported" message and after a minute or two, it would flash again and show the game back again without me doing anything besides waiting.

The issue started to increase and within a day or two, the message doesn't seem to go away at all now and I am unable to turn on my PS3. It just constantly says "Mode not supported" with a black screen (no sound also).

I have been facing this issue for quite some time now. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Reset the video output**

Start with your PS3 turned off. With the PS3 off (showing a solid Red light) if you hold the power button down until you hear two beeps it will force the PS3 to forget any saved video output settings and boot up at a lower resolution. It will then take you through the Optimal Resolution set up.

**Replace the HDMI cable**

If the above doesn't work, it may be necessary to replace the HDMI cable.

Comment: I have tried this, but it just solves the issue temporarily (like for a day or two) and then it starts to happen again. I also tried to change the cable but to no avail. Any other suggestion ?

Comment: You could try a factory data reset, but as a last resort you most likely will need have it serviced.

Comment: I connected my ps3 with the RGB cable and performed a factory data reset. Then started my ps3 while on RGB, when it started , it notified me that it had detected an HDMI cable connection and asked  if I wanted to switch to HDMI, I selected ok the screen flashed and went blank again. Nothing afterwards. Do you think its an issue with the HDMI port ?

Comment: Unfortunately, it sounds like it. Either on your PS3, or on your TV.

Comment: Ok I narrowed it down to my PS3. It seems that the TV port is fine becuase when I connect it my laptop with the same TV using the same HDMI cable as I use with my ps3, it displays fine. So I guess its an issue with the ps3 port. Even though I am much sad to hear this, but still, your answer helped me out, and thus, accepted. !

Answer (score 1):

I just fixed the problem.  All you have to do is turn the PS3 off, then when you turn it back on, you hold the power button for five seconds. The ps3 will autodetect the right resolution for the tv you're using.

Answer (score -3):

I say that you go to your sources of your tv and change it to video than after 20 seconds change it to hdmi or just unplug and plug the hdmi wire back one time